# Chat Data for NLP Text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a set of chat conversations (each conversations with 100 sentences) and corresponding labels (No other meta features). but there are only 5 observations per labels. I know that we need lots of observations per label to create a good classification model. So to increase the training data , is it a good practice to split the large text conversation into different sentences and considering each sentence as a distinct observation.(Now I will have 500 observations per label).What would be the effect on the performance of the classification model ? Would it increase or decrease or would have no effect on the performance? if there is change in performance, why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So to increase the training data is it a good practice to split the large text conversation into different sentences and considering each sentence as a distinct observation.

It can increase the performance but this is tricky, depends on the exact sentence after splitting it the labels should be valid for individual sentences. (hard to automate)

- A good technique to increase data size is to translate data to other language and translate it back to same language.(Usefulness depends on use case) .
- You can look at tools like [Markovify](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify) [its primary use is for building models of large corpora of text and generating random sentences from that ]

Implementation's here : https://www.kaggle.com/jpmiller/augmenting-the-data